# Terminal: command which clears only outputs of historical commands

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Is their in terminal a command similar as **clear** or **ctrl+l** which only clears the output of commands I passed in.

For example my shell looks like this

```
martin@martin-LINCPLUS-P4:~/Git$ 
martin@martin-LINCPLUS-P4:~/Git$ branch
Command 'branch' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install rheolef
martin@martin-LINCPLUS-P4:~/Git$ git branch
* feature-a
  main
martin@martin-LINCPLUS-P4:~/Git$
```

my aim view after the command should like this

```
martin@martin-LINCPLUS-P4:~/Git$ 
martin@martin-LINCPLUS-P4:~/Git$ branch
martin@martin-LINCPLUS-P4:~/Git$ git branch
martin@martin-LINCPLUS-P4:~/Git$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> followed by the command `history` will show you recent commands without their output.

You will see a number in the front of these previous commands. You can execute any command again by entering `!###`, where `###` is the number you see before the command.

Other ways to re-execute previous commands are 1) arrow up until the command reappears;  2) reverse search: hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> then type a few letters from the command until it appears.

Once you quit a current terminal session, the commands of the current session are appended to the file `~/.bash_history`. You can see these commands with the command `cat ~/.bash_history`.